# How do I change/choose the file path in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to access a .txt file in Python and I can't figure out how to open the file. I ended up copying the contents into a list directly but I would like to know how to open a file for the future.

If I run this nothing prints. I think it's because Python is looking in the wrong folder/directory but I don't know how to change file paths.

```
sourcefile = open("CompletedDirectory.txt").read()
print(sourcefile)
```

Comment: Try providing the `"/absolute/path/to_your_file.txt"`

Comment: where is the .txt file in relation to the python script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `CompletedDirectory.txt` is probably empty.

If Python could not find the file, you would get a `FileNotFoundError` exception:

```
>>> sourcefile = open("CompletedDirectory.txt").read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CompletedDirectory.txt'
```

Note that using `read()` in this way is not recommended. You're not closing the file properly. Use a context manager:

```
with open("CompletedDirectory.txt") as infile:
    sourcefile = infile.read()
```

This will automatically close `infile` on leaving the `with` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current working directory:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Then just concat it with the file container directory

```
os.path.join("targetDir", "fileName")
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have cut instead of copied when put it into Python. I should have checked that but this was very helpful